# PC SAS trim/delete

Tags: sas, trim, substr

Afternoon all,

I have a dataset with a variable called list_name.

Some of these list names are prefixed with 'Y_' (eg: HNEWCARD vs: Y_HNEWCARD)

For the purposes of my analysis I want to treat this as the same variable.

So in short, i want to delete the first two characters of the variable name if they start 'Y_'.

I've played around with some trims and substr but can't get any valid output!

Sounds simple, but its gone over my head today!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if substr(list_name,1,2)='Y_' then list_name=substr(list_name,3);

Comment: Brilliant! I tried very similar to this - example below. But as lengths of list_names varied so much I was making erronous changes. if substr(list_name,1,2)='Y_' then list_name=substr(list_name,3,10);

Comment: SUBPAD will help you there (if you wanted to do that rather than just skip the 3rd argument, for some reason), as you can ask for the longest possible length and it will pad others with spaces.